# How can I create a notification bubble, similar to the notification badge on iPhones' menus, using JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I am new to JavaFX and I'm trying to create a notification badge similar to the image below. [image]

It is to be used as a notification count and I was hoping to place it over the corner of a JavaFX button. My problem is that I cannot find a native solution that supports this. Can anyone recommend an approach?

Thanks

Comment: Excellent question!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this? Maybe not so pretty (I'm not an artist), but I think it may cover the solution.

[image: Sample solution]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="${button.prefHeight}" prefWidth="${button.prefWidth}" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutY="8.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Click " AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <StackPane layoutX="57.0" layoutY="-13.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-10" AnchorPane.topAnchor="-10">
         <children>
            <Circle radius="10.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE">
               <fill>
                  <RadialGradient centerX="0.5" centerY="0.5" radius="0.8164556962025317">
                     <stops>
                        <Stop color="#ff361beb" />
                        <Stop color="WHITE" offset="1.0" />
                     </stops>
                  </RadialGradient>
               </fill>
            </Circle>
            <Label text="5" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution (and used and ellipse instead of a circle to show double digit numbers in a nicer way), simply add an Ellipse and Label after the Button in the fxml file like this:

```
<Button fx:id="btnAddMarking" layoutX="640.0" layoutY="60.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#stopRecording" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="205.0" styleClass="button-remark" text="Add marking" visible="false" />
<Ellipse fx:id="elMarking" fill="#ffaa00" layoutX="841.0" layoutY="63.0" radiusX="16.0" radiusY="12.0" stroke="#ffaa00" strokeType="INSIDE" visible="false" />
<Label fx:id="lblMarking" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="829.0" layoutY="51.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" styleClass="label-white" text="42" visible="false" />
```

Ive used this trick several times now: JavaFX simply plots the elements on screen in the order they are present in the fxml file, so you can always get an element 'on top' of another one (and scene builder shows it correctly too).

Well, at least in JavaFX 17, as that's what I'm using at the moment.